# Access object within foreach loop

Tags: php, object

I've got a list of objects:

```
 0 => 
    object(stdClass)[550]
      public 'node_title' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      public 'nid' => string '1473' (length=4)
      public 'node_language' => string 'nl' (length=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[552]
      public 'node_title' => string 'Test2' (length=5)
      public 'nid' => string '1321' (length=4)
      public 'node_language' => string 'nl' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[553]
      public 'node_title' => string 'Test3' (length=5)
      public 'nid' => string '602' (length=3)
      public 'node_language' => string 'nl' (length=2)
```

And I loop over them using a foreach loop:

```
foreach($view->result as $key => $value) {

}
```

So, if every time the foreach loops, 1 object is fetched, right?
But how can I access one item of the object? I've tried with `0->nid`, `$key->nid`,... but nothing worked... How can I do so?

Comment: Have a look at the [`foreach` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). As the variable names already suggest, `$key` is the index of the array element, while `$value` is, surprise, the value. If you don't know which of these to use, you can simply inspect them with `print_r($key)` and `print_r($value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($view->result as $key => $value) {
    // Here, $value is the current object
    echo($value->node_title);
}
```

Comment: Oh, well. This is embarrassing... Thanks though :)

Comment: No problem :) Everyone misses something now and again